# Disease that you eat

Tags: riddle, word

> I am something that you eat
>   But I am also something which is called disease
>   I am something that is grown in the ground  but I am not veggie
>   But I am also something that can grow mainly on your feet.

Who am I?

Sorry for such an awful rhyming...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are a

> Fungus

`I am something that you eat`

> [Mushrooms can be a delicious fungus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edible_mushroom).

`But I am also something which is called disease`

> One can have a fungal infection, like [Thrush](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Candidiasis) in the mouth, or Athlete's Foot* on the feet.

`I am something that is grown in the ground but I am not veggie`

> Fungus usually grows on or in the ground, though it can grow in a lot of places

`But I am also something that can grow mainly on your feet.`

> See above, re: Athlete's Foot.
>
>  * *I am not linking to this one, because there's a gross-ass picture there*

Comment: Made me look! Arguably, the other's even more so!?!!

Comment: @paulevans haha I thought about that after posting, but for some reason it just doesn't gross me out as much

Comment: oh really? i can change that

Comment: @manshu hahaha! Stop it! Now you're gonna make me look!

Comment: @PaulEvans [Here](http://c0379342.cdn2.cloudfiles.rackspacecloud.com/35358_0_athlete_s_foot_4.jpg) and [here](https://i.ytimg.com/vi/ZkuBCSoNb10/hqdefault.jpg)...just in case you really don't want to...best i could find :p

Comment: @manshu nooooooooooooooooooo...

Comment: Guys... what happened here.

Answer (score 5):

Even though the question is answered. But I found out another answer that I'd like to share. It is

> Corn

---

I am something that you eat

> Yup.

But I am also something which is called disease

> Yes, there really is a disease called [corn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callus#Corns).

I am something that is grown in the ground but I am not veggie

> Speaking from a botanical point of view, corn is classified as a grain. And yeah they are grown on the ground.

But I am also something that can grow mainly on your feet.

> As you can see from the [linked pictures](http://www.howhunter.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/get-rid-of-corns-on-your-toes.jpg)